# usage of github organization secret in a github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to use an github organization secret in my github action workflow but cannot get it working.

Github released that new feature on May 14th (https://github.blog/changelog/2020-05-14-organization-secrets/). Of course I read the documentation and added a new organization wide secret ( on https://github.com/organizations/(myOrganization)/settings/secrets ). The secret "Repository access" is set to "private repositories".

I used the same secret name which I used in 4 private repositories before. The workflows of those repositories use the secret in that way:

```
- uses: actions-hub/gcloud@master
        env:
          PROJECT_ID: ${{ env.ARTIFACT_PROJECT }}
          APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
          CLI: gsutil
        with:
          args: cp ....
```

The access via `${{secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS}}` works when I "override" the organization secret in every project (which was the case before the organization secret feature was released).

When I remove the project secret, the secret is not there and yield an empty value.

Does anyone had the same issue and knows how to solve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem while using the free plan.

I cant find the doc, but it states under https://github.com/organizations/yourFreeOrganization/settings/secrets that **Organization secrets cannot be used by private repositories with your plan.**

But then again, if you had a free plan you wouldn't even have the option to create a new secret shared only by private repositories anyway

Comment: Where exactly did you read that? At your provided link (for my organization) there is not such information. Also I set the secret to be used to private repositories explicitly.

If there was a limitation for the free plan it should be documented here https://github.com/pricing .

How did you resolve your issue? By upgrading to the team plan?

Comment: can confirm, when you enter to the organization secrets page, on top of your secrets it says: "Organization secrets cannot be used by private repositories with your plan."